# Test "300 threads" from VPS scripting, is it possible? how?

Tags: multithreading, testing, web-scraping, recaptcha, captcha

A certain **[captcha solving service](https://webscraping.pro/captchasolutions-test)** offers "**300 threads** with unlimited solves" plan. We want to test the service. Is it possible to properly manage the 300 threads, provided we have VPS to run scripts from? Possible languages/environments to use are `Node.js` or `JAVA` or `PHP` or `Python`.

If yes, explain how?

My partner has critical mind of that:

> All threads will be divided by the number of processor cores, and
> those that are located on the same core will not go parallel, but will
> simply transfer control to each other. Kind of ineffective...

Comment: Probably not this kind of thread...

Comment: @Macmade, could you explain why?